# How to retrieve an array list

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to retrieve an array list using visualforce page, for example, evry user is identified by his name, email, adress and a table of folders, evry folder has an ID, and name.

How can I do this, please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving objects in SFDC is done with SOQL. You can read more about it [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm).

For example, to retrieve a the name and id of every user in the org:

```
User[] users = [select Id, Name, from User];
```

If you want to show the information in a Visualforce page, you should make the *users* variable a property. Then you can use [apex:dataTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_dataTable.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) or apex:repeat to show the values.